# 2sxc : how to reuse custom input type in another application?

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

I "know" how to make some basic custom input types but now I want to use this types in my other applications. I know that I can make copy for each off app I create but I am iterested if the "Ghost Content Type" is the way to do this that way that I have only one "code base" for custom input type? Or is better that I just make copies to another apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

To ensure that the input-type is available everywhere, you must add it to the list of available input types on the global level - usually in zone 1 app 1.

Then also create the configuration type in zone 1 app 1, scope system, always share... and you're ready to go :)